# How can I filter data using Redux but keeping the old state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am working on a search functionality with Redux but I am having some issues.

These are the actions related to the search stuff:

```
export const passengersDataAction = passengersData => ({
  type: ActionTypes.PASSENGERS_DATA,
  // This is the array of objects that I need to search through
  payload: { passengersData }, 
});

export const searchParamAction = searchParam => ({
  type: ActionTypes.SEARCH_PARAM,
  // This is the param that I need to send to passengersData
  // in order to get a new array of objects based on the searchParam
  payload: { searchParam },
});
```

Reducers:

```
const initialState = {
  passengersData: [],
  searchParam: '',
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.PASSENGERS_DATA](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      passengersData: action.payload.passengersData,
    };
  },

  [ActionTypes.SEARCH_PARAM](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      searchParam: action.payload.searchParam,
    };
  },
};
```

Btw this is how the array of objects looks:

```
[
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Marcos Alonso",
  "address": "Sabana",
  "phone": "712321222",
  "pickup": 0,
  "cardinalpoint": "N",
  "latitude": "9.93683450",
  "longitude": "-84.10991830",
  "timestamp": "2019-02-19 21:23:46",
  "dropofftimestamp": null,
  "pickuptimestamp": null,
  "deleted": null,
  "driver": 1
 },
 ...
]
```

This is something I am trying to get it to work:

```
   [ActionTypes.SEARCH_PARAM](state, action) {
    //In filter you can add your own logic to get the data
    const searchedData = state.passengersData.filter((passenger) => passenger.name === action.payload.searchParam);

       return {
         ...state,
         passengersData: searchedData,
         searchParam: action.payload.searchParam,
       };
    },
```

But with the code above, it is replacing the `passesngerData` with 'searchedData'. I need to keep the original `passengerData` so I guess I can create a new state in redux store and return it from the reducer. My question is, how can I do that? Every time I type something in the input, the whole `passengersData` array goes away and the searched is not returning anything.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I am going to add the code regarding the components that handle the search functionality:

```
// imports
import { searchParamAction } from '../../screens/HomeScreen/actions/homeScreen';

class AllPassengersList extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      searchParamActionHandler,
      searchParam,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
          <View>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={text => searchParamActionHandler(text)}
              value={searchParam}
              placeholder="Search..."
            />
          </View>
        <Text>{searchParam}</Text>
        <PassengerCardBasedOnRoute searchParam={searchParam} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AllPassengersList.propTypes = {
  passengersData: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array]).isRequired,
  searchParam: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
  searchParamActionHandler: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func]).isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      navigationStore: store.homeScreen.navigation,
      searchParam: store.homeScreen.searchParam,
      passengersData: store.homeScreen.passengersData,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      searchParamActionHandler: value => {
        dispatch(searchParamAction(value));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(AllPassengersList);
```

The component above is the one holding the search text input.
The one below is the one where I render the array of objects that I need to filter:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PassengersInfo from './PassengerInfo';

import { popupsModalsAction } from '../PopupsModals/actions/popupsModals';

const PassengerCardBasedOnRoute = ({
  navigationStore,
  passengersData,
  popupsModalsActionHandler,
  searchParam,
}) => {
  return (
      <View>
        {passengersData.map(info => (
            <PassengersInfo
              key={info.id}
              id={info.id}
              searchParam={searchParam}
              cardinalpoint={info.cardinalpoint}
              name={info.name}
              address={info.address}
              datetime={info.timestamp}
            />
          ))}
      </View>
  );
};

PassengerCardBasedOnRoute.propTypes = {
  passengersData: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array]).isRequired,
  searchParam: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      passengersData: store.homeScreen.passengersData,
      searchParam: store.homeScreen.searchParam,
    }),
  ),
)(PassengerCardBasedOnRoute);
```

So `passengersData` is the array which handles the data I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not filter the data in redux store and assign the result to the variable you filtered data from because this way on every search you wold loose you original data, instead just store the `searchParam` in store and write a selector that returns you the filtered result and use that in the component

```
const filterSelector = (state, props) => {
    return state.passengersData.filter((passenger) => passenger.name === state.searchParam);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
   const searchData = filterSelector(state, props);
   return {
       searchData
   }
}
```

and you reducer would simply be

```
[ActionTypes.SEARCH_PARAM](state, action) {
       return {
         ...state,
         searchParam: action.payload.searchParam,
       };
    }
```

EDIT: Updating code with example

```
// imports
import { searchParamAction } from '../../screens/HomeScreen/actions/homeScreen';

class AllPassengersList extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      searchParamActionHandler,
      searchParam,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
          <View>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={text => searchParamActionHandler(text)}
              value={searchParam}
              placeholder="Search..."
            />
          </View>
        <Text>{searchParam}</Text>
        <PassengerCardBasedOnRoute searchParam={searchParam} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AllPassengersList.propTypes = {
  passengersData: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array]).isRequired,
  searchParam: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
  searchParamActionHandler: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func]).isRequired,
};

const filterSelector = (passengersData, searchParam) => {
     return passengersData.filter((passenger) => searchParams == '' || passenger.name === searchParam);
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
      navigationStore: store.homeScreen.navigation,
      searchParam: store.homeScreen.searchParam,
      passengersData: filterSelector(state.homeScreen.passengersData, state.homeScreen.searchParam),
}),
export default compose(
  connect(

    dispatch => ({
      searchParamActionHandler: value => {
        dispatch(searchParamAction(value));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(AllPassengersList);
,
```

Comment: Hi, @Shubham Khatri. I just updated my code. See the EDIT part. I didn't get very well the first part of your answer so I am unable to adapt that to my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Reacting What I meant is that you shouldn't be overwriting the passengerData while searching in store, instead write a filter function that returns the filtered data . Updated the answer